# Handling user input in C

Tags: c, string, input

In C, I am writing a program which is taking in user input than comparing it to see which output it should use. I am finding it problomatic and was wondering if someone could give me a hand. So far I have:

```
while(cmd[0] != EOF){
     fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin); /** Takes in user input and stores it in cmd **/
     if(cmd[0] == '\n')
         printf("%s> ", cwd);
     else if(strcmp(cmd, "ls") == 0)
         printf("I will list everything");
}
```

Any ideas?
Basically it is just ignoring any user input when there is some.

P.S. The variable cwd is just a string.

Comment: What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: Basically it is ignoring any user input except a new line.

Comment: @Michael Dillon - It makes perfect sense if it's declared `char cmd[128];`. If it's a dynamic array then you're right.

Comment: @Chris- the point is that it is not declared at all in the question. sizeof is supposed to be used only with completely defined types and we cannot see if char *cmd is completely defined.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to ask a more specific question.  A couple of problems I can see:

1. The `strcmp()` call.  `fgets()` will retain the newline (if any) from the input line.  Given that your program looks like it's implementing a command line shell, comparing with `"ls"` is probably never going to be true - you would need to use `strncmp()` or include the `\n` in the string you're comparing against.
2. You're not checking the return status from the `fgets()` call - you'll probably want to do that to avoid disaster if someone types some bad control characters in at your prompt.
3. As I mentioned above, your program looks kind of like a command shell.  If that's the case, your prompt (the `"%s> "`, right?) will only get printed out if the user enters a blank line as input.  Presumably you would want the prompt to get printed out each time around the loop.
4. How do you expect `cmd[0]` to ever be `EOF` for your loop to complete?  The `fgets()` man page says:

   > Upon successful completion, **`fgets()`** and **`gets()`** return a pointer to the string.  If end-of-file occurs before any characters are read, they return **`NULL`** and the buffer contents remain unchanged.

   That sounds to me like you can't ever get `EOF` in your buffer by using `fgets()`.